# Ruby on Rails 4 Test Failure (deletion functionality)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running into a failure running bundle exec rake test.  The file in question, is test/integration/users_index_test.rb.  It looks like the below:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @admin     = users(:michael)
    @non_admin = users(:archer)
  end

  test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
    log_in_as(@admin)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
      unless user == @admin
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete',
                                                    method: :delete
      end
    end
    assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
      delete user_path(@non_admin)
    end
  end

  test "index as non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@non_admin)
    get users_path
    assert_select 'a', text: 'delete', count: 0
  end
end
```

Running the rake test, I get the following "failure":

```
1) Failure:
UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links [/Users/********/workspace/myapp/test/integration/users_index_test.rb:19]:
<delete> expected but was
<User 19>.
Expected 0 to be >= 1.

19 runs, 49 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Any ideas what is wrong?  Thanks.

View (index.html.slim):

```
- provide(:title, 'All users')
h1
  | All users

= will_paginate

ul.users
  - @users.each do |user|
    = render @users

= will_paginate
```

_user.html.slim:

```
li
  = gravatar_for user
  = link_to user.name, user
  - if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user)
    |  | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
```

Comment: And what does the view look like?

Comment: Double check your `users.yml` fixture file and make sure you have the line `admin: true` for `:michael`.

Comment: the michael user does have admin true in the users.yaml file.  The views have been added to the question above.

Comment: any other ideas please?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with slim syntax, but if you are going to `render @users` with a partial, you shouldn't have the `@users.each do |user|` line. Alternatively, you can keep the `each` block and `render user` (the block's parameter). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: What `!current_user?(user)` does? Can you post the code of it? Also will your test pass if you remove the ` && !current_user?(user)` part from your view?

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. It the code/exercise is from chapter 9 of [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users). The full code of my exercise – **with the same mistake/bug** – is [online](https://github.com/cuducos/railstutorial-with-slim). Any ideas?

Comment: @rmagnum2002 `!current_user?(user)` checks if the `user` in the loop is the user who is logged in. Here is [the source](https://github.com/cuducos/railstutorial-with-slim/blob/e6a21a7986d22e61298eacf24871d1084c80f428/app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the problem is in your template: when you call `render @users` Rails already iterate through the list of users you have at `@users`, so you don't need the `.each do` part:

```
...
ul.users
  - @users.each do |user|
  = render @users
...
```

You could do it simply this way:

```
...
ul.users = render @users
...
```

I'm a newbie following the same tutorial, so, not sure if it is a good answer. Let me know if it helps…

Answer (score 2):

Was getting exactly the same problem.  For me the problem was with the users.yml file.  The admin user I was logging in as in the test had a duplicate entry in the **user.yml file**.

```
dom:
  name: Dom Example
  email: dom@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true

dom:
  name: James Brown
  email: godfather@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is because your slim syntax is not good.

The fix was to check if the partial: *_user.html.slim* contained the text which you are trying to assert in test, in this case your *users_index_test.rb* contains:

```
first_page_of_users.each do |user|
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
  unless user == @admin
    assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete',
                                                method: :delete
  end
end
```

You are asserting `text: 'delete'`,that is, test is looking for such text in your *index.html.slim* which is again filled with your partial *_user.html.slim* (there is an explanation for this in tutorial, because `render @users` is actually looking for them in a partial) and guess what you have a wrong slim syntax.

Try mine solution for
**_user.html.slim**:

```
li
  = gravatar_for user, size: 50
  = link_to user.name, user
  - if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user)
    /These 3 lines below are my slim hack for inserting -> " | " <- in front of "delete" /!
    =<
    | 
      |
    =< link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "You sure?"}
```

railstutorial.org by mhartl (added for a sake of a search)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error.

It was due to me placing code for the _user.html.erb in the index.html.erb. make sure your _user.html.erb is correct.

index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had commas in my users.yml file.  Not sure why I added them, but once I took them out if fixed my issue.

> michael: 
>    name: Michael Example
>    email: michael@example.com
>    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
>    admin: true
>    activated: true
>    activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

vs.

> michael:
>    name: Michael Example
>    email: michael@example.com
>    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
>    admin: true,
>    activated: true,
>    activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>